# Uniqueness checking in distributed systems

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, unique, uniqueidentifier

The context of my question: A distributed system of nodes, on each node I have an application and it's own DB, all the DBs are having the same structure. A synchronisation is possible between the different nodes but the ownership of each time can be attributed only to one node in a time.
Each Node can process Data separately, but I have an issue with verifying some unique identifiers over all the system. In order to resolve this, I implemented a centralised DB where all nodes can store their unique data once processed, a verification is done using this DB to make sure that the data is consistent over all the system.

I don't have any control on the data content, it is computed based on a user input. I cannot randomise or add anything but I must guarantee that it is unique. When processing data for the same user on 2 different nodes, the system must make sure that no collision happen....
This system is very slow and have some limitations, the system is covering different regions of the world and this is making the verification more difficult.

Do you have any proposition on how can I optimise this system?

Comment: We would need some more information as to what "ownership of each time" means, and what are the collisions you are encountering today?  There are several design patterns to deal with parallel processing.  Hashing data so each node is responsible for something else.  Or a central "dispatcher" which every node accesses first to get a key or the data for the processing, and that prevents duplication.  Or adding the node's personal key as part of the data identifier.  And there are many more.  But it depends first on what is the behavior of the collision you want to prevent.

Comment: Thank you Amir, the ownership here can be ignored, it is only for modification properties...
The main point is regarding the duplication:
- N1, N2 and N3 are nodes, the first one is located in US, the second in Germany and the third in China.
The same user will send data to be processed on the 3 nodes, one of the duties is to guarantee that the user data is processed only once and not duplicated.

Comment: There are 2 scenarios:
1)- The user provide only a start value or an algorithm of data generation, the same algorithm will run on the 3 nodes using different ranges and the system must ensure the no collision.
2)- The user provide all data to be consumed, the system here must prevent the user from sending the same data to 2 nodes
I hope it is clear, thank you in advance for your comments!